# Send email notifications to Users who have flagged a node

Tags: 8, rules, emails, flags, notifications

For a site, I 'Events' which have a datetime field for the start time of the event. We also have 'Flags' to allow Users to add specific events to their calendar.

Now, we would like to send Users email notifications when an event that they have 'flagged' is about to start (that is, 30 minutes before it starts).

If this best achieved with Rules module, or is another method more appropriate?

Comment: Custom code with [Job Scheduler](https://drupal.org/project/job_scheduler) is more appropriate as [Rules scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules/issues/2683463) hasn't been ported to D8 yet.

Comment: Thank you @NoSssweat, unfortunately, I can't install any modules that aren't covered by the security policy for this site.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Yes, I ended up writing a custom module to do it. Let me know if it would be of help to you and I'll post it here! :)